# Name of book about faxing people

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, nazis

I have been trying to identify a book that I read years ago. It is about time travel and involved “faxing” people.  The Nazis were trying to perfect this in World War II. However, people were caught in stone and never made it.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86090/help-me-identify-this-book-that-uses-cloning-for-space-travel one of these, perhaps?

Comment: "Faxing" is the word they used in Dan Simmons' Ilium/Olympos saga, but that doesn't involve Nazis or WWII.

Comment: How long ago is "years ago" - ten years, twenty, fifty? Was it new then or older? What else can you remember about it? Have a look at [the suggestions in this FAQ](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [edit] as much as you can into the question.

Comment: Faxing people is also a big deal in Wil McCarthy 's [Queendom of Sol](http://www.wilmccarthy.com/queendom.htm) books, but again no Nazis

Answer (score 3):

This is only a partial match, but as it does involve "faxing" people, and the technology was developed by the Nazis, I'm suggesting *[The Wire Continuum](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?81708)* by Stephen Baxter and Arthur C. Clarke. This is a short story, first published in Playboy in 1988, and later anthologised in *The Collected Stories of Arthur C. Clarke*.

One of Clarke's earliest published works was *[Travel by Wire](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?65148)* from 1937, where he considered the consequences of transporting people by converting them to electrical signals and passing hem down telephone cables. He revisited this idea with Baxter to consider an alternate history where this concept was first invented by Nazi Germany:

> all that lurid stuff of secret Nazi labs which had come within a hair
> of developing an A-bomb for Hitler — or even a way of transporting
> people by telephone wires, so Hitler could have mounted a new
> electronic Blitzkrieg even from the heart of his collapsing Reich!

and later developed to first provide interplanetary travel, and later to travel to the stars. The point of view character is Henry Forbes, who flew Spitfires in the Second World War, became the first man on the moon when he delivered a receiving station there in 1976, and eventually travelled across the galaxy.

One drawback of the system was that:

> the quantum translation process at the heart of the Wire relied on
> having an inert mass to transform at the receiver end

The consequences of not having a supply of such inert matter were not explicitly descried though.